# Getting images from a string path to be viewed in an imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have some picture paths stored in a datastore and i am trying to convert them into drawables and display the in my image view, for some reason im getting a null pointer exception. Can someone please help me? Thanks

```
String pathName = selectedPlayer.getPicture(); 
Toast.makeText(this, pathName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: What does your logcat prints?

Comment: java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: what are the values in pathName ? Is it local image path(SDCARD) or web url ?

Comment: logcat usually also prints  line number at which the exception occured

Comment: localimage.. Images are stored on the emulators gallery and the paths are stored in a datastore.

Comment: this is causing the nullPointerException Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);

Comment: i would consider that you have the findviewbyid for imageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check file name is not null

then check that first if file **exists** or **not**

```
if(pathName!=null && pathName!="") <--CHECK FILENAME IS NOT NULL
{
    File f = new File(pathName);
    if(f.exists())  <-- CHECK FILE EXISTS OR NOT
    {
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
You have to initialize your imageview first like

```
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);
```

Comment: hmm now the null pointer exception is here: imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

Comment: @NiraliPatel Have you initialized imageView using findViewById() ?

Comment: `imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);`

Answer (score 1):

Look at `imageView` it should not be null.

And after that try this :

```
bm = null;
try {
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageView);
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```